# Pass variables between Promises and functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a problem. 
I have to do two different SOAP calls to retrieve two list of vouchers and then use these lists to do a check on them and to do some job.
I put the two calls in different Promise functions because I want start the job on the lists after the call returned its result.
This is the first Promise call:

```
    let vouchers = function(voucherTypeList){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    const categoryId = "1000";
    let args = {
      "tns:CategoryId": categoryId
    };
    var header = {
      "tns:Authenticate": {
        "tns:UserName": soapVoucherWsdlUsername,
        "tns:Password": soapVoucherWsdlPassword
      }
    };

    // let voucherTypeList;
    voucherClient.addSoapHeader(header);
    voucherClient.GetVouchers(args, function(err, result) {
      console.log("DENTRO GET VOUCHERS");
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        writeResponse(res, '200', err);
      } else {
        //++++++++++++++++++++++
        //voucherTypeList is what I want to return to the main function
        voucherTypeList = mapGetVoucherTypeListResponse(result);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++
      }
      resolve("done 1");
    });
  });
}
```

This is the second Promise call:

```
let issuedVouchers = function(accountId) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const categoryId = "1000";
    let args = {
      "tns:CategoryId": categoryId,
      "tns:CheckRedeem": true,
      "tns:IncludeRedeemed": false,
      "tns:CardId": accountId
    };
    var header = {
      "tns:Authenticate": {
        "tns:UserName": soapVoucherWsdlUsername,
        "tns:Password": soapVoucherWsdlPassword
      }
    };

    let issuedVoucherList;
    voucherClient.addSoapHeader(header);
    voucherClient.GetVouchers(args, function (err, result) {
      console.log("DENTRO GET ISSUED VOUCHERS");
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        writeResponse(res, '200', err);
      } else {
        //++++++++++++++++++++++
        //issuedTypeList is what I want to return to the main function
        issuedTypeList = mapGetVoucherTypeListResponse(result);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++    
      }
      resolve("done 2");
    });


  });
}
```

And this is the main function, with the Promise flow:

```
function getAvailableVoucherTypes(req, res) {
  var accountId = req.params.accountId;
vouchers(voucherTypeList).
    then(issuedVouchers(accountId)).
        then(function() {
        //here I want to use voucherTypeList and issuedTypeList
        //and do some jobs on them
        console.log("OK");
        });
}
```

How can I do this? I tried many solutions, but I'm not able to see *voucherTypeList* and *issuedTypeList* in the main function.

Comment: resolve is there for a reason... Whatever you pass to resolve will be passed to the then callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` callbacks are getting the value of what you pass to the `resolve` function in your promises. You are currently passing arbitrary strings, which is useless... But for the demonstration, let's keep those and just log their values in your main script:

```
function getAvailableVoucherTypes(req, res) {
  var accountId = req.params.accountId;
vouchers(voucherTypeList).
    then(function(result){
         console.log(result); //done 1
         return issuedVouchers(accountId);
    }).
        then(function(result) {
          console.log(result); //done 2
        //here I want to use voucherTypeList and issuedTypeList
        //and do some jobs on them
        console.log("OK");
        });
}
```

I'll let you play with your promises to pass the right variables...

Now, it seems that your 2 calls do not need to be sequential, so let's make them parallel, it's gonna be slightly easier for us too.

```
function getAvailableVoucherTypes(req, res) {
  var accountId = req.params.accountId;
  var promises = [vouchers(),issuedVouchers(accountId)]
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
      //In Promise.all, the results of each promise are passed as array
      //the order is the same as the order of the promises array.
      var voucherTypeList = results[0];
      var issuedTypeList = results[1];
  });
}
```

BONUS: I do not want to complicate this task too much before you grasp it correctly. So I won't add more code. But note that you should use reject too, instead of handling your errors in every promise, you should reject them when things go wrong. Just `reject(err)` and add a second callback to your main script's then to handle any error that may happen. If you keep resolving your promises that did not work, you will not be passing the elements you are expecting and you'll need to add checks over every step.

Let's modify the GetVouchers callback to fit what I suggest.

```
voucherClient.GetVouchers(args, function (err, result) {
  console.log("DENTRO GET ISSUED VOUCHERS");
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve(mapGetVoucherTypeListResponse(result));  
  }
});
```

Once it is done on both your promises, we can change your main script to handle the error accordingly.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
   //Handle success like above.
},function(err){
   //Handle error.
    console.log(err.stack || err);
    writeResponse(res, '200', err);
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'm trying your solution! thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: see promisejs.org their examples are simply to follow and explanations clear.

Comment: Thanks this works!!! I used the 2nd solution, with parallel soap call. Thank you very much.

Comment: Tell me more about the reject. I put reject(err) in the soap call it's ok with this?

Comment: added more in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Salketer